# What cable type (TRS or TRRS) is appropriate for connecting my Zoom H5 to my Sony A6400?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, zoom

So, I have a Sony A6400 camera that I want to connect directly to my Zoom H5 audio recorder in order to record my sound directly onto the camera video without bothering to sync it up in my post production software.

Now for the connection required between my H5 to my A6400 does it need to be a TRS cable or a TRRS cable? Second question is what is best for quality- OFC or OCC cable or does it even matter really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a TRS cable. Make sure you reduce the line-out level in your Zoom H5, otherwise the audio in your camera will peak all the time.

The quality/purity of the copper in the cable is irrevelant. This OFC vs. OCC is just marketing-blah-blah. Apparently no manufacturer has been able to prove any discernible difference.

A real problem is that these 3.5mm jacks and cables aren't durable in the field. They just break too easily.